# Reverse text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to find the text inside **double quotes** in an array of strings and reverse it.

```
var arrayTest = [
    'Why is it that heartache almost always precede after the act of first love',
    'Love, you say, is \"a two way thing\"',
];

for(var i = 0; i < arrayTest.length; i++){
    var ret = "";
    if ( /"/.test( arrayTest[i] ) ){
        ret = arrayTest[i].split("").reverse().join("")
    } else {
        ret = arrayTest[i];
    }

    console.log(ret);
}
```

I am getting this:

> Why is it that heartache almost always precede after the act of first
>   love
>
> "gniht yaw owt a" si ,yas uoy ,evoL

But I what I want to get is this:

> Why is it that heartache almost always precede after the act of first
>   love
>
> Love, you say, is "gniht yaw owt a"

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Try using a regex with a `replace`.

Comment: Why delete the old question and repost it again? Coincidentally, my comment on the deleted one looked very similar to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45701940/6692606) you are getting now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your code reverses the entire string when it finds a `"` character. You need to extract just the portion of the string that's between the `"` characters.

An easy solution would be to use a regex with [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and a function that reverses the matched quoted string.

```js
var arrayTest = [
  'Why is it that heartache almost always precede after the act of first love',
  'Love, you say, is \"a two way thing\"',
];

arrayTest.forEach(function(str) {
  var newStr = str.replace(/"[^"]*"/g, function(match) {
    return match.split('').reverse().join('');
  });
  console.log(newStr);
});
```